Puppeteer temp file creation and how to avoid that
I'm encountering a problem with Puppeteer where it's generating a large number of temporary files, consuming significant disk space, and ultimately leading to service errors (HTTP 500). How can I configure Puppeteer to ignore or limit the creation of these temporary files to prevent this issue?
Without creating temp files need to work or those should be removed after puppeteer script closes and terminated.
